# ttf2ufm_x2gs on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ghostscript, truetype

I use national delivery service windows software for genarating and printing labels installed with Wine. The program works fine, but when I try to print the document printer uses different fonts for barcode. They provided 4 different ttf fonts with program to install it on system. I've installed them on wine and now they are OK in program. But problem comes when I try to print the files with printer or with cups-pdf the result is that the bar code looks completly different. I found out that I should install those fonts to ghostscript which transforms, but there is a problem. When I try to install font using ttf2ufm_x2gs which should install font to ghostscript I get following error code in terminal:

/usr/bin/ttf2ufm_x2gs: 82: .: 3:To many files open

I copied default config.cfg to folder with fonts. Only change that I've made is added ENCDIR and MAPDIR paths.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows software must not be embedding the fonts into the ps/pdf as needed. The Xserver might be using the fonts correctly to display the result yet ghostscript can't embed the fonts needed for printing. The TTF fonts have probably not been added to a Fontmap file in the ghostscript library path or fontpath as required. The [ttf2ufm_x2gs](http://manpages.org/ttf2ufm_x2gs) looks very complicated just for setting up fonts to be used by ghostscript. I suspect your fonts and Fontmap are still not working with ghostscript as needed. I don't use CUPS so can't help with that. The CUPS probably runs ghostscript to send the job to the printer and ghostscript can't find the TTF fonts.

I use the /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/ directory for my own fonts to keep them separate from the dist packages so they won't be disturbed by package updates. Then the /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/Fontmap file can be edited to tell ghostscript how to locate your needed TTF files. Be sure the Fontname is correct because that is difficult to discover with TTF files. The fontforge program can give the correct Fontname if unknown.

The Fontmap result should have the 4 TTF fonts listed, for example:

```
% font in same directory
/Fontname1   (font1.ttf) ;

% font in different directory
/Fontname2    (/path/to/font2.ttf) ;

% alternate style
(Fontname3)    (font3.ttf) ;

% alternate style in different directory
(Fontname4)    (/path/to/font4.ttf) ;
```